# Restrictions on Application.Inputbox and cell formated as text

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following simple excel table with this formula
in cell A1:

```
= MID(B1;1;2))
```

which gives me a value of 30.

```
        A           B              C
1      30        30:30
2
3
4
5
```

Now I want to apply the following loop in a macro to it:

```
Sub test()
    Do
        first_row = Application.InputBox("Below which row new row(s) should be inserted?" _
                                         & vbCr & "Min: " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") & "  Max: 500")
        If first_row = False Then Exit Sub
        If first_row > 500 Or first_row < Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") Then MsgBox ("Row has to be >= " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value & " and <= 500")
    Loop Until first_row <= 500 And first_row >= Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") Or first_row = False
End Sub
```

In this macro the user gets a message box in which he has to enter a number. This number must be between the value in cell A1 (in this case: 30) and 500.

However, right now once the user enteres a number over 100 the loop does not accept the value although it is between 30 and 500.
It only accepts values under 100.

So far I figured that the issue might be caused by cell B1 which is formated as "TEXT". Otherwise it won't be possible to use "30:30" in this cell.

Therefore, I tried to change the formula in A1 to the following:

```
= VALUE(MID(B1;1;2)))
```

It does work but then the system also allows values below 30.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: The problem is not the value of `A1` but the return value of [Application.InputBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx). This will be text until you use `Type:=1` or convert it with `Val(first_row)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `Application.Inputbox` type parameter = 2 will return a numeric value.  Declaring `first_row As Long` will ensure that first_row  is always a numeric value.

```
Sub test()
    Dim first_row As Long
    Dim prompt As String

    Do
        prompt = "Below which row new row(s) should be inserted?" & vbCr & "Min: " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") & "  Max: 500"

        first_row = Application.InputBox(prompt:=prompt, Type:=1)

        If first_row = 0 Then Exit Sub

        If first_row > 500 Or first_row < Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") Then MsgBox ("Row has to be >= " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value & " and <= 500")

    Loop Until first_row <= 500 And first_row >= Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
End Sub
```